# Prove that $z^{2n} - 2 a^n z^n \cos (nθ) + a^{2n}=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[z^2-2az\cos\left(\theta+\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)+a\right]$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, factoring

> Prove that $$z^{2n} - 2 a^n z^n \cos (nθ) + a^{2n}= \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[z^2-2az\cos\left(\theta+\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)+a\right].$$

I personally know a similar question stating that
$$z^{2n}+1=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[z^2-2z\cos\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}\right)+1\right].$$

And we can show this by using the roots of $z^{2n}+1=0$, i.e., multiplying each $(z-z_{n})$ and correspond each term to its conjugate.

However, I found this approach not that practical to be used in the above more generalised situation. I also tried Induction, and it turns out that it will be very tedious to right out all the terms.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24z%5E%7B2n%7D%20-%202%20a%5En%20z%5En%20cos%20n%5Ctheta%20%2B%20a%5E%7B2n%7D%24&p=1), I found the AoPS thread [Nice product](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1111810p5071274) with your question, as well as the related [Product of square of distances from vertices of a polygon of radius a](/q/868590/602049) and [An interesting integral $\int{\dfrac{x^m}{x^{2m}+1}dx}$](/q/3886239/602049) posts here.

Comment: Please use \cos to produce $\cos$. Also write $\cos(n\theta)$ instead of $cosn \theta$. Use \ldots instead of just writing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer that I have attained eventually.
[image]

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 2):

First, it suffices to prove this identity for $a=1$ (why?)

Then, we need to prove the following polynomial identity:
$$
z^{2n}-2\cos nθ\cdot z^n+1=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(z^2-2\cos(\theta+2\pi k/n)\cdot z+1).
$$
Now note that
$$
z^2-2\cos\varphi\cdot z+1=(z-e^{i\varphi})(z-e^{-i\varphi}) 
$$
Can you continue now?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the factorization
$$z^n-b^n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(z- b e^{i\frac{2\pi k}n})$$
to
\begin{align}
z^{2n} - 2 a^n z^n \cos nθ+ a^{2n}
=&  \left[z^n - \left(a e^{i\theta}\right)^n \right]\left[z^n - \left(a e^{-i\theta}\right)^n \right]\\
=& \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[z- a e^{i(\theta+\frac{2\pi k}n)}\right]\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[z- a e^{-i(\theta+\frac{2\pi k}n)}\right] \\
=& \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[z^2-2az\cos\left(\theta+\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)+a\right]
\end{align}